# Phonegap Multiple webviews on BlackBerry

Tags: cordova, webview, blackberry-10

We are thinking on using phonegap for some projects but still have some doubts.
Is it possible to have multiple webviews on phonegap on BalckBerry 10?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to develop an app with multiple webview for blackberry 10.I have found many apps that use webview and have been release in stores like IOS,android,blackberry etc.It is possible i have managed to achieve it with my app,I could post a link but i only uploaded it to app store yesterday,its not available for download in blackberry world yet.But check it out in other stores if you like https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/gargash-insurance/id836602923?mt=8